# GeeksforGeeks: Rotate matrix by 90 degrees

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, matrix

Please review the code readability, I would like to have an easier to follow code.
Thanks

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace ArrayQuestions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inplace-rotate-square-matrix-by-90-degrees/
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class RotateMatrix90
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Rotate3x3Test()
        {
            int[,] mat =
            {
                {1, 2, 3},
                {4, 5, 6},
                {7, 8, 9}
            };
            int[,] expected =
            {
                {3, 6, 9},
                {2, 5, 8},
                {1, 4, 7}
            };
            rotateMatrix(mat);
            for (int r = 0; r < mat.GetLength(0); r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < mat.GetLength(1); c++)
                {
                    Assert.AreEqual(expected[r, c], mat[r, c]);
                }
            }

        }

        void rotateMatrix(int[,] mat)
        {
            int size = mat.GetLength(0);
            for (int x = 0; x < size / 2; x++)
            {
                for (int y = x; y < size - x - 1; y++)
                {
                    int temp = mat[x, y];             // save 1
                    mat[x, y] = mat[y, size - x - 1]; // move 3 into 1
                    mat[y, size - x - 1] = mat[size - x - 1, size - y - 1]; // move 9 into 3
                    mat[size - x - 1, size - y - 1] = mat[size - y - 1, x]; // move 7 into 9
                    mat[size - y - 1, x] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/184/

Comment: @Acccumulation omg that's the best!! funny man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple improvement for readability could be to eliminate the `- 1` in the indices by replacing `size` with `max = mat.GetLength(0) - 1;`:

```
void rotateMatrix(int[,] mat)
{
  int max = mat.GetLength(0) - 1;
  for (int x = 0; x < (max + 1) / 2; x++)
  {
    for (int y = x; y < max - x; y++)
    {
      int temp = mat[x, y];             // save 1
      mat[x, y] = mat[y, max - x]; // move 3 into 1
      mat[y, max - x] = mat[max - x, max - y]; // move 9 into 3
      mat[max - x, max - y] = mat[max - y, x]; // move 7 into 9
      mat[max - y, x] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

You could also make a pair of vars for `max - x` and `max - y` as :

```
void rotateMatrixReview(int[,] mat)
{
  int max = mat.GetLength(0) - 1;
  for (int x = 0; x < (max + 1) / 2; x++)
  {
    for (int y = x; y < max - x; y++)
    {
      int xmax = max - x;
      int ymax = max - y;
      int temp = mat[x, y];             // save 1
      mat[x, y] = mat[y, xmax]; // move 3 into 1
      mat[y, max - x] = mat[xmax, ymax]; // move 9 into 3
      mat[xmax, ymax] = mat[ymax, x]; // move 7 into 9
      mat[max - y, x] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Just for the fun: another approach could be:

```
void Swap(int[,] mx, int r1, int c1, int r2, int c2)
{
  int tmp = mx[r1, c1];
  mx[r1, c1] = mx[r2, c2];
  mx[r2, c2] = tmp;
}

void rotateMatrix(int[,] mat)
{
  int m = mat.GetLength(0) - 1;

  // l = level in the matrix from outer = 0 to inner 
  for (int l = 0; l < (m + 1) / 2; l++)
  {
    // o = offset along rows and cols
    for (int o = 0; o < m - 2 * l; o++)
    {
      Swap(mat, l, l + o, l + o, m - l);
      Swap(mat, m - l - o, l, m - l, m - l - o);
      Swap(mat, l + o, m - l, m - l - o, l);
    }
  }
}
```