# Rotate matrix clockWise and counter clockWise

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, interview-questions, matrix, complexity

This code is a mix of the same question one time rotating to the right and one time to the left.
I tried to simplify the code since I'm struggling with all of the indexing here.

https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-image/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rotate-matrix-90-degree-without-using-extra-space-set-2/

> Rotate the image by 90 degrees (clockwise).
>
> Note:
>
> You have to rotate the image in-place, which means you have to modify
>   the input 2D matrix directly. DO NOT allocate another 2D matrix and do
>   the rotation.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Given input matrix =  [   [1,2,3],   [4,5,6],   [7,8,9] ],
>
> rotate the input matrix in-place such that it becomes: [   [7,4,1],
>   [8,5,2],   [9,6,3] ] Example 2:
>
> Given input matrix = [   [ 5, 1, 9,11],   [ 2, 4, 8,10],   [13, 3, 6,
>   7],   [15,14,12,16] ],
>
> rotate the input matrix in-place such that it becomes: [   [15,13, 2,
>   5],   [14, 3, 4, 1],   [12, 6, 8, 9],   [16, 7,10,11] ]

Please review this code as I am trying to simplify it in order to be able to have a good short solution for a coding interview. I can't memorize this logic of course I just want to have a solid simple solution in mind.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace ArrayQuestions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inplace-rotate-square-matrix-by-90-degrees/
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class RotateMatrix90
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void RotateClockWise2x2Test()
        {
            int[][] mat =
            {
                new[]{0,1},
                new[]{2,3},
            };
            int[][] expected =
            {
                new[]{2,0},
                new[]{3,1}
            };
            RotateClockWise(mat);
            int size = mat.GetLength(0);
            for (int r = 0; r < size; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < size; c++)
                {
                    Assert.AreEqual(expected[r][c], mat[r][c]);
                }
            }
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void RotateClockWise3x3Test()
        {
            int[][] mat =
            {
                new[]{1, 2, 3},
                new[]{4, 5, 6},
                new[]{7, 8, 9}
            };
            //tranpose then flip horizotally
            //1,4,7
            //2,5,8
            //3,6,9
            int[][] expected =
            {
                new[]{7, 4, 1},
                new[]{8, 5, 2},
                new[]{9, 6, 3}
            };
            RotateClockWise(mat);
            int size = mat.Length;
            for (int r = 0; r < size; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < size; c++)
                {
                    Assert.AreEqual(expected[r][c], mat[r][c]);
                }
            }
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void RotateCounterClockWise2x2Test()
        {
            int[][] mat =
            {
                new[]{0,1},
                new[]{2,3},
            };

            //0,2
            //1 3
            int[][] expected =
            {
                new[]{1,3},
                new[]{0,2}
            };
            RotateCounterClockWise(mat);
            int size = mat.GetLength(0);
            for (int r = 0; r < size; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < size; c++)
                {
                    Assert.AreEqual(expected[r][c], mat[r][c]);
                }
            }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void RotateCounterClockWise3x3Test()
        {
            int[][] mat =
            {
                new[]{1, 2, 3},
                new[]{4, 5, 6},
                new[]{7, 8, 9}
            };
            //tranpose then flip horizotally
            //1,4,7
            //2,5,8
            //3,6,9
            int[][] expected =
            {
                new[]{3, 6, 9},
                new[]{2, 5, 8},
                new[]{1, 4, 7}
            };
            RotateCounterClockWise(mat);
            int size = mat.Length;
            for (int r = 0; r < size; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < size; c++)
                {
                    Assert.AreEqual(expected[r][c], mat[r][c]);
                }
            }
        }
        //moving elements clockwise (90 degrees to the right)
        public void RotateClockWise(int[][] matrix)
        {
            Transpose(matrix);
            ReverseRows(matrix);
        }
        //moving elements counter clockwise
        public void RotateCounterClockWise(int[][] matrix)
        {
            Transpose(matrix);
            ReverseCols(matrix);
        }
        private void Transpose(int[][] matrix)
        {
            int size = matrix.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i; j < size; j++)
                {
                    Swap(ref matrix[i][j], ref matrix[j][i]);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ReverseRows(int[][] matrix)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0, k = matrix.Length - 1; j < k; j++, k--)
                {
                    Swap(ref matrix[i][j], ref matrix[i][k]);
                }
            }
        }
        private void ReverseCols(int[][] matrix)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0, k = matrix.Length - 1; j < k; j++, k--)
                {
                    Swap(ref matrix[k][i], ref matrix[j][i]);
                }
            }
        }

        void Swap(ref int i, ref int j)
        {
            int temp = i;
            i = j;
            j = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are mixing your code in with the unit tests. I suggest to make seperate classes for tests and code.

Comment: I had to visit the link to find the spec of `n`x`n`. You could make our task helping you easier if you include crucial information in the question :)

Comment: You have solved this one time before, just for a [normal array](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/220769/geeksforgeeks-rotate-matrix-by-90-degrees/220796#220796) - with a O(n^2) complexity. You can easily change that solution for a jagged array and to handle clock wise rotation.

Comment: @henrik I hate this solution. The indexing there is too complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Performance

Time complexity for your algorithm is \$O(N²+N²/2)\$. If you find a way to combine `Transpose` \$O(N²)\$ and `ReverseCols` \$O(N²/2)\$ in a single run, you could get \$O(N²)\$ in worst case.

Edit: given Henrik's good eye, you have already come up with a solution before that adheres to the optimized complexity. So, apply it here.